# jQuery on("click") not working after $(window).on('hashchange') and emptying main div

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, handlebars.js

I'm coding a cordova app with a home page and a setting page. It must be a single page application so body contents change by changing the url hash, I used $(window).on('hashchange') and "a" tags with href="#setting" on home and href="#" on setting page to change content

There's a button on home page and a one on setting, both have an `on click` jQuery event.

the button on home page works fine when app initializes. But if I click on the link with href="#settings", the button on setting page  won't do anything though it has a on click event. (going back to homepage, home's button also not working anymore)

UPDATE: the #main div removes each time hash changes, and a new #main div is created. can this be the reason? changing dom structure? if yes, how can I fix it? my views are generated in HomeView object.

here's the code:

```js
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.route();
        this.url= /^#settings$/ ;
        this.receivedEvent();

    },

    receivedEvent: function() {
        var self= this;

        $('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
            self.save();
        });
        $('#btnLocate').on('click', function () {
            self.calc();
        });

        $(window).on('hashchange', this.route.bind(this));
    }
    ,

    play: function (pos) {
        //do something
    },

    route: function () {
        var hash= window.location.hash;

        if(!hash) {
            if(this.homePage) {
                this.showPage(this.homePage);
            }else {
                this.homePage=new HomeView().render();
                this.showPage(this.homePage);
            }
            //this.receivedEvent();
            return;
        }

        var self= this;
        if(hash.match(this.url)) {
            if(this.settingPage) {
                this.showPage(this.settingPage);
            }else {
                this.settingPage= new SettingView(self.crl).render();
                this.showPage(this.settingPage);
            }
            //this.receivedEvent();
        }
    },

    showPage: function (page) {
        if($('#main')) {
            $('#main').remove();
        }
        $('body').append(page.el);
    },

    calc: function () {
        //do something
    },

    save: function () {
        //do something
    }

};

app.initialize();
```

home view this:

```js
var HomeView= function () {

    this.initialize= function () {
        this.el=$('<div/>').attr('id','main');
    }

    this.render= function () {
        this.el.html(HomeView.template);
        return this;
    }

    this.initialize();

}

HomeView.template= Handlebars.compile($("#home-tpl").html());
```

and setting view is the same.

There are two commented lines. I added them to check if it works, and suprisingly works!!! BUT if I add an alert inside showpage function every time I click on "a" tags to change the url, alert happens twice the time before, it's so weird! it may get to 32 alert in a row after 5 clicks on a tag!!!
I use Handlebars.js for templates. and run the code in browser.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to modify your code a bit as follows:

1) `onDeviceReady:` should have jQuery event handler initialization code as follows:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.route();
    this.url= /^#settings$/ ;
    this.receivedEvent();

    var self= this;
    //using event delegation technique to attach event listner
    $(document).on('click','#btnSave', function () {
        self.save();
    });
    $(document).on('click','#btnLocate', function () {
        self.calc();
    });

    $(window).on('hashchange', this.route.bind(this));

},
```

Above code will get executed only once.

2) `receivedEvent:` shouldn't have jQuery event handler attachment code:

```
receivedEvent: function() {

},
```

3) commented `//this.receivedEvent();` lines should be as it is.

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks! but this time even the button on home page doesn't work at all, I think it's because cordova app must wait until device ready events. I run the page on a cordova server.

Comment: could you please move event listener attachment code to `onDeviceReady:` as above

Comment: I'm sorry. just now moved listeners to `onDeviceReady` and it's the same as the first. and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: are you getting any JS error. you can check them in browser's console.

Comment: no, there's no error. I used console.log to make sure by clicking on buttons something may happen, but I get nothing in my console.

Comment: would you take a look at my update? I don't now how to test that theory?

Comment: are you sure that you are using event delegation `$(document).on('click',` way to attach listener?

Comment: I think so, since it works first time I visit the homepage. I just uncommented `this.receivedEvent();` and add a `$('#btnSave').off('click');` for every listener. and it seems it works ok. but I think it's not a good way!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127525/discussion-between-niloofar-and-vijayp).